# Referencing a column on a table to a column on another table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was reading another question on here regarding referencing columns from two separate tables but was  a little confused if it addressed my issue. What's going on is I have two tables, Destination and Booking. The Destination table has a column for location_id, and the Booking has a column for location, and I am trying to reference location in Booking table from location_id column in Destination table.

Here is my table for Booking(migration)

```
class CreateBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :bookings do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :start_date
      t.string :end_date
      t.string :email
      t.integer :location

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

 
end
```

and here is my table(Migration) for Destination

```
class CreateDestinations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :destinations do |t|
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.integer :location_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My Models are setup currently as

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  # belongs_to :reservation, optional: true
  has_many :destinations, :class_name => 'Destination', :foreign_key=> 'location_id'
  validates :name, :start_date, :end_date, :email, presence: true
end


and 

class Destination < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bookings,  :class_name => 'Booking', :foreign_key=> 'location'
end
```

Am I currently referencing the columns correctly, or is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you should write your migrations depends on the association between your models. Foreign keys go onto tables that have a `belongs_to` association.

Can a single Booking have multiple Destinations? If the answer is no, you need to change the association in your Booking model to `belongs_to :destination` and then put a `:destination_id` on your bookings table (you can give it a custom name like `:location_id` if you want but the convention is to use the model name).

If a single Booking can have multiple Destinations, and surely a single Destination can have multiple Bookings, then you have a many-to-many relationship. In that case you will not put foreign keys on the destinations table, nor the bookings table. Instead you will need a join table between them and that's where the foreign keys go.

Rails gives 2 different ways to declare many-to-many relationships. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many.

If you want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, your models would look like this:

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :destinations
end

class Destination < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bookings
end
```

And the migration would look like this:

```rb
class CreateBookingsAndDestinations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :bookings do |t|
      # ...
    end

    create_table :destinations do |t|
      # ...
    end

    create_table :bookings_destinations, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :booking
      t.belongs_to :destination
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is will help me understand this a little better, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat: Based on your question I'm assuming you want a booking to have a destination. If you want a destination to many bookings and vise-versa, Sean's answer is great.*

I think you're misunderstanding how foreign keys / associations work in databases.

It sounds like you want a column in the bookings table to "reference" a value column in the destinations table (or maybe the opposite), as in:

`bookings.location -> destinations.location_id` or maybe `destinations.location_id -> bookings.location`.

That's not typically what we mean by "reference" in a relational database. Instead, when you say that a table (for example, a 'comments' table) references another table (for example, a comments table references a user table), what we typically mean is that we're storing the primary key column of the referenced table (e.g. the user's id) in a column in the first table (e.g. `comments.user_id --> users.id`).

From an english language standpoint I expect that you want a booking to refer to a destination, so I'm going to assuming we want a the booking table to reference/refer to the destinations table, like this:

`booking.location -> destinations.id`

In Ruby on Rails, the convention is to name a column that stores an association with the same as the table it references, plus `_id`, like so the convention would be this:

`booking.destination_id -> destinations.id`

A common way to create this in a migration would be with:

```
add_reference :bookings, :destination
```

When adding a reference in a database you *almost* always want to index by that value (so that you can do `Bookings.where(destination_id: @destination.id)` and not kill your database).  I am also a strong advocate for letting your database enforce referential integrity for you, so (if your database supports it) i'd recommend the following:

```
add_reference :destinations, :booking, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

This would prevent someone from deleting a destination that has a booking associated with it.